# C program: print prime number between 1 to 100

Tags: c

I was just wondering why my code doesn't work. Yes I know that it's easy to find answers online but I just wanted to delve in why the things I do doesn't function well rather than simply getting answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("all prime numbers between 1 and 100\n");
    for (i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) {
        if (i % !i != 0 && i>0 ) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of lengthy explanations why you didn't find answers, why not tell us what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: What's supposed to do  `i % !i` ?

Comment: @Cid nothing, `!=` has higher precedence than `&`, it is `(i & (!i != 0)) && (i>0)` and it is always false.

Comment: Then it's time to start debugging. Forgive me for asking, but do you even understand what `i % !i != 0 && i>0 ` does? Because I don't. :)

Comment: It does not work because the algorithm is incorrect. It has not been very well thought through, as shown by the `i>0` part always being `true`.

Comment: To check if a number is prime this is the simplest algorithm: is it divisible by 2? Yes => not prime. Is it divisible by 3? Yes => not prime. Is it divisible by 5? Yes = > not prime, is it divisible by 7? Yes => not prime, etc.

Comment: ah sorry i thought it meant if i divided by something that is not itself is has a remainder that is equal to zero, that means it has a factor aside from itself, so I thought i divided by j that is not itself is not equal to zero means it doesn't have other factor

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed yourself, there are tons of example code for this out there, so there's little point for me in showing how to calculate primes. So instead, I show how to debug your code. In this case I'd doe something like this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) {
    printf("i: %d !i: %d\n", i, !i);
    printf("i \% !i != 0: ", i % !i != 0);
    if (i % !i != 0 && i>0 ) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

The exact printouts is something that you have to find out for yourself. But start with individual values, and then look at more complicated expressions. Also, use parenthesis whenever unsure. I don't know exactly how the expression in your if statement is parsed. I can think of several possibilities. Like:

```
((i % !i) != 0) && (i>0)
(i % (!i != 0)) && (i>0)
(i % !i) != (0 && i>0)
```

The point here is that your code does not work, and you have a very messy expression that is hard to understand exactly what it does. So use parenthesis.

Another thing you should do with that expression is to motivate each part with words. Can you explain why you have `i>0`? Because that's always true, to it's completely pointless. Instead of asking why it doesn't work. Try to explain to yourself why it should work. Get more and more detailed until you find something that you cannot explain. Then you probably have your bug there.

The definition of a prime is that it is an integer strictly greater than one, and is not divisible by any other integers than itself and and one. So now it's your job to explain how `i % !i != 0 && i>0` should be able to check if `i` is an integer or not. And take explicit examples. For instance, if `i` is 5, describe the process when `i % !i != 0 && i>0` checks if it is divisible by 2. Then explain how it checks for divisibility by 3.

The very simple question to your answer why it does not work is because the algorithm is wrong. :)

Comment: ah thank you very much for the comment. But may I ask what \% is ? I searched it online again and it says that "\% is illegal because it has the syntax of a C escape sequence, but no defined meaning." I am a little confused. Thank you for the tips I will bear that in mind.

Comment: @edwinalai Please provide a link. Would be interesting to read. When I read the documentation it seems like you're right. It should be `%%` instead of `\%` but both seem to work when I try them.